# PHP echo variable outside of while loop returning last value

Tags: php, while-loop, echo

Hope everyone has had a good new year

I am trying to echo a value from a loop however it just returns the **last** value of a for loop

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info btn-sm\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#modal-username\">Username</button></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>"; // Don't worry the password is hashed
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['admin'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    // Assign variables to use out of loop
    $id = $row['id'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $password = $row['password'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $admin = $row['admin'];
}
```

On my modal body is

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <p><?php echo $username; ?></p>
</div>
```

I've tried using `.=` instead of `=` but that just concatenates all the usernames together

I understand it is probably an easy fix and have tried looping through the variable assigning section but it just returns 0

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Rain Just to stress, that column was only there for me to test echoing rows into a table so it won't be included in the final part

Comment: Which username should be in the modal?

Comment: The first one in the db, however I tried all the buttons and the same result

Comment: You should clarify that in the question.

Comment: Im not, Im trying to display all the users so I can then use modals to edit them and the button brings up the modal with that username in

Comment: If this is a Bootstrap 4.0 modal, see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content for how you can automatically transfer data from the table into the modal when the user clicks on a button.

Comment: You must have a jquery code for btton to load or to popup the modal  .  Can u post that part in the question.

Comment: @Ramyz It's a bootstrap modal so it's all included in bootstrap already, so no extra code required for the modal

Comment: oh yes! there are 2 way to load and show modal. 1- Via data attributes  2- Via JavaScript/Jquery

Comment: Lol, this question was a brilliant misdirection. I was so busy wondering if it was worth answering the title that I missed the real issue: trying to use php for a JavaScript job. Any interactivity in the browser is JavaScript driven.  The modal must get its information from JavaScript (whether data attribute or ajax), not php directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i do in this kind of case.

*change the loop button*

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-info btn-sm modal-trigger\" data-uname='" .  $row['username'] . "'>Username</button></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>"; // Don't worry the password is hashed
    echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['admin'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

*and change modal to*

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <p id="uname-select"></p>
</div>
```

jquery code

```
$('body').on("click", '.modal-trigger', function() {
    var GetUname = $(this).attr('data-uname');
    console.log('Selected Username: ' + GetUname);
    $('#uname-select').html(GetUname); // load the <p> tag with username selected
    $('.modal').modal(); // Make Modal & Show
});
```

give this a try..

Answer (score 0):

The `$username` is a **variable** an it can keep a **value** only
if you wants to keep all of usernames then should use **Array**s
some thing like :

```
$id=$username=$password=$email=$admin=Array(); 

while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Assign variables to use out of loop
    $id[] = $row['id'];
    $username[] = $row['username'];
    $password[] = $row['password'];
    $email[] = $row['email'];
    $admin[] = $row['admin'];
}

echo $username[0];// first username
echo $email[1];// second email
```

**UPDATE**
you can `limit` the query results like :

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,'select * from tablename limit 20;');
```

if you wants to fetch some data without fix length :

```
$username=Array();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $username[] = $row['username'];
}

echo count($username);// how many? as integer
```

or after `while` loop you can use `for` loop

```
for ( $i=0; $i<count($username); $i++){

    echo $username[$i].'<br>';

}
```

**UPDATE 2**
if you try to store and show first username only then you can do :

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    if(!isset($username)){
        $username = $row['username'];
    }
}
echo $username;// first only
```

or some shorter :

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $username = $username ?: $row['username'];
}
echo $username;// first only
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know how many rows there are since the database could be expanding etc. Is there any way to implement that when you don't know how many rows there are?

Comment: you can **limit** results in database query also may you set **order** , although may you want fetch some data that have not a fix lengh , i will update the answer